# Java best way to order the list instead using multiple loops

Tags: java

How to arrange the below list of objects in a efficient way,

```
public class ItemDto {

    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private Long rootItemId;
    private List<ItemDto> subItems = new ArrayList<ItemDto>();
}
//getters and setters
```

The input array list like below

```
// 0 = Rootitem
// Sub items contains root items id

List<ItemDto> allItems = new ArrayList<ItemDto>();

allItems.add(new ItemDto(1,"A",0));
allItems.add(new ItemDto(2,"B",1));
allItems.add(new ItemDto(3,"C",1));
allItems.add(new ItemDto(4,"D",0));
allItems.add(new ItemDto(5,"E",4));
allItems.add(new ItemDto(6,"F",4));
```

Need to create a final items list which contains `ItemDto` with its subelements from the `allItems`  list.

The final list like below

```
IteamDto -> Id1
   |
   -> ItemDto -> Id2
   |
   -> ItemDto -> Id3
IteamDto -> Id4
   |
   -> ItemDto -> Id5
   |
   -> ItemDto -> Id6
```

Comment: You want to build a tree structure? Only 1 level deep? Or is there no restriction?

Comment: looks to me like ItemDTO and IteamDTO should be two different classes.

Comment: @BenjaminM its only one level deep

Comment: @Stultuske splitting two class can be ease but I am exploring it to perform in single class

Comment: @Ramakrishna then why do you give them different names in your expected outcome?

Comment: Why don't you just use a `TreeMap` or `LinkedHashMap`? Then you get your 1-level tree out of the box and don't have to write any code

Comment: you can use like this..List<ItemDto> allItems = new ArrayList<ItemDto>();
List<ItemDto> subItems1 = new ArrayList<ItemDto>();
subItems1.add(new ItemDto(2,"B",1,null));
subItems1.add(new ItemDto(3,"C",1,null));
allItems.add(new ItemDto(1,"A",0,subItems1));